# Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have written the below code for LCS. It works for many cases but breaks for the one below. I do not understand where my code is breaking. Please help. The code is in C#

```
namespace LongestCommonSubsequenceBF
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string B = "AAACCGTGAGTTATTCGTTCTAGAA";
        string A = "CACCCCTAAGGTACCTTTGGTTC";
        //find LCS in A,B starting from index 0 of each
        int longestCommonSubsequence = LCS(A, B, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(longestCommonSubsequence);
        Console.Read();

    }

    //Find the longest common subsequnce starting from index1 in A and index2 in B
    //Pass A as shorter string
    public static int LCS(String A, String B, int index1, int index2)
    {
        int max = 0;
        if (index1 == A.Length)
        {
            //You have reached beyond A and thus no subsequence
            return 0;
        }
        if (index2 == B.Length)
        {   //you may reach end of 2nd string. LCS from that end is 0
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i = index1; i < A.Length ; i++)
        {
            int exist = B.IndexOf(A[i],index2);
            if (exist != -1)
            {
             //   found = true;

                int temp = 1 + LCS(A, B, i + 1, exist + 1);
                if (max < temp)
                {
                    max = temp;
                }


            }


        }
        return max;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the desired result, and what do you get instead?

Comment: `IndexOutOfRange` is the exception you get?

Comment: @Dave: the desired result is 13. I get 14

Comment: @Jani: No I do not get that. This is handled in my code :)

Comment: Note: i am just calculating the length of the longest sequence. I am not calculating the solution itself

Comment: This will never work because startIndex for IndexOf method is always 0.

Comment: @Tomas: No, Please go to msdn website and do a in depth study of indexof. Then you _may_ understand. Else post a question in stackoverflow and i will answer it :)

Comment: I read msdn and it says same think i said. You are always passing 0 as second param without any modification elsewhere. Msdn is saying "The search starts at a specified character position."

Comment: In subsequent recursive calls, I am NOT passing 0 but exist +1 . Take a pen and paper and convince yourself

Comment: You're right, sorry. Missed that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you think your algorithm is broken? The longest common subsequence is `ACCTAGTATTGTTC`, which is 14 characters long:

```
string B = "AAACCGTGAGTTATTCGTTCTAGAA";
              ^^^ ^ ^^ ^^^^ ^^^^

string A = "CACCCCTAAGGTACCTTTGGTTC";
             ^^^  ^ ^^ ^^  ^^ ^ ^^^
```

(I modified your algorithm to return the sequence instead of just the length.)

Comment: Thanks. Surprised to see that answers given in columbia lectures are wrong. Check this out: http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F09/lcs.pdf

Comment: By the way, nice idea to return the subsequence

Comment: where can we find the modified algorithm?

Comment: @Arjang: This is left as an exercise to the reader. ;-) If you understand how the original algorithm works, this modification should not be too hard.

Comment: @Heinzi can you show source code for returning the sequence?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk: As I said, this is left as an exercise. Hint: You will need strings for max, temp and the return value instead of ints.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments seen under the accepted answer, looks like there's an interest in seeing how the **sequence** is created. That's why I decided to add this answer.

This is a complete example using `C# 12` in `.NET 8`. And tested using `NUnit 3`.

### Visualizing the grid

Let's start with a simple example. Find *Longest Common Subsequence* between words: **FISH** and **FOSH**.

We only really care about how to fill cells from `(1,1)` to `(word1.Length,word2.Length)` and basic idea of filling those cells is:

1. If the characters in row and col match, the value in this cell is `(value of top-left neighbor) + 1`. And also store this character in this cell.
2. If the letters don't match, grab: `MAX(value of top neighbor, value of left neighbor)`.

| word2.len+1 cols word1.len+1 rows |  | col=0 | col=1 | col=2 | col=3 | col=4 word2 len=4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Word2 Word1 |  | **F** | **O** | **S** | **H** |
| row=0 |  | 0 *(0,0)* null | 0 *(0,1)* null | 0 *(0,2)* null | 0 *(0,3)* null | 0 *(0,4)* null |
| row=1 | **F** | 0 *(1,0)* null | 1 *(1,1)* 'F' | 1 *(1,2)* null | 1 *(1,3)* null | 1 *(1,4)* null |
| row=2 | **I** | 0 *(2,0)* null | 1 *(2,1)* null | 1 *(2,2)* null | 1 *(2,3)* null | 1 *(2,4)* null |
| row=3 | **S** | 0 *(3,0)* null | 1 *(3,1)* null | 1 *(3,2)* null | 2 *(3,3)* 'S' | 2 *(3,4)* null |
| row=4 word1 len=4 | **H** | 0 *(4,0)* null | 1 *(4,1)* null | 1 *(4,2)* null | 2 *(4,3)* null | 3 *(4,4)* 'H' |

#### Backtracking the grid

The basic idea is:

1. If the grid cell has a character, move towards diagonal.
2. If the grid cell has no character, move towards the left or top neighbor (whichever is bigger).

This gives the sequence. In this case, it's "FSH".

(4,4)  (3,3)  (2,2)  (2,1)  (1,1)

### Implementing the grid and backtracking

```cs
namespace Algorithms.DynamicProgramming;

public record Cell(int Value, char? Character);
public static class LongestCommonSubsequence
{
    public static Cell[,] Find(string word1, string word2)
    {
        var grid = new Cell[word1.Length + 1, word2.Length + 1];
        for (var row = 0; row <= word1.Length; row++)
        {
            // First row and first column are padded with zeroes, so we put nullable char in those places
            char? currentRowLetter = row == 0 ? null : word1[row - 1];
            for (var col = 0; col <= word2.Length; col++)
            {
                char? currentColumnLetter = col == 0 ? null : word2[col - 1];
                // Create the padding, so something like: grid[row - 1, col - 1] won't get you into Index out of bounds exceptions
                if (row == 0 || col == 0)
                {
                    grid[row, col] = new Cell(0, null);
                }
                else if (currentRowLetter == currentColumnLetter)
                {
                    var topLeftNeighbor = grid[row - 1, col - 1];
                    grid[row, col] = new Cell(topLeftNeighbor.Value + 1, currentRowLetter);
                }
                else
                {
                    var topNeighbor = grid[row - 1, col];
                    var leftNeighbor = grid[row, col - 1];
                    grid[row, col] = new Cell(Math.Max(topNeighbor.Value, leftNeighbor.Value), null);
                }
            }
        }

        return grid;
    }

    // Backtracking the grid
    public static string GetLcSubsequence(Cell[,] grid)
    {
        var lcs = new Stack<char>();

        // Only go through the words' length portion of the original grid.  For eg: (word1.Length,word2.Length) to (1,1)
        // Don't go to the padded row/ column, that's why -1
        var rows = grid.GetLength(0) - 1;
        var cols = grid.GetLength(1) - 1;
        
        while (rows > 0 && cols > 0)
        {
            // If you get a character, go towards diagonal
            if (grid[rows, cols].Character.HasValue)
            {
                lcs.Push(grid[rows, cols].Character!.Value);
                rows--;
                cols--;
            }
            // Otherwise, just go towards the left or top neighbor (whichever is bigger)
            else
            {
                if (grid[rows - 1, cols].Value > grid[rows, cols - 1].Value)
                    rows--; // If the top neighbor:grid[row - 1, col] is bigger, go towards it
                else
                    cols--; // If the left neighbor:grid[row, col - 1] is bigger, go towards it
            }
        }
        
        return new string(lcs.ToArray());
    }
}
```

### Testing the code

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using Algorithms.DynamicProgramming;

namespace Algorithms.UnitTests.DynamicProgramming;

public class LongestCommonSubsequenceTests
{
    [Test]
    public void LCS_Finds_Longest_Common_Subsequence()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string word1 = "AAACCGTGAGTTATTCGTTCTAGAA";
        const string word2 = "CACCCCTAAGGTACCTTTGGTTC";

        // Act
        var grid = LongestCommonSubsequence.Find(word1, word2);
        var subsequence = LongestCommonSubsequence.GetLcSubsequence(grid);
        var subsequenceLength = grid.Cast<Cell>().MaxBy(c => c.Value)!.Value;

        // Assert
        Assert.That(subsequence, Is.EqualTo("ACCTAGTATTGTTC"));
        Assert.That(subsequenceLength, Is.EqualTo(14));
    }
}
```

[image]