# How to compare 2 string arrays and find all consecutive matches and save indices?

Tags: c#, arrays

For example, if I have the following 2 arrays:

```
string[] userSelect = new string[] {"the", "quick", "brown", "dog", "jumps", "over"};
string[] original = new string[] {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
```

I'm trying to compare the userSelect array against the original array and get all consecutive matches based on index. The userSelect array will always be made up of strings from the original array. So the output would be like the following:

```
int[] match0 = new int[] {0, 1, 2}; // indices for "the quick brown"
int[] match2 = new int[] {4, 5}; // indices for "jumps over"
int[] match1 = new int[] {3}; // index for "dog"
```

The userSelect array length will never exceed the original array length, however it can be shorter and the words can be in any order. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Anything tried yourself? It seems not too complicated.

Comment: I've tried a bit, it's not as easy as I thought it would be, because certain words can be used more than once and I'm looking for longest consecutive matches. For example, in the above "the" can be in the sentence twice and both would have to be checked.

Comment: Sounds like a slight varient of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem. You could convert your array into a delimited string and use whatever algorithms solve that problem to solve your problem. I'm inferring from your comments you're really just trying to find the longest one, not every combination of matches even though at first glance that's how your question reads: BTW there's an implementation already posted for c# on the stack already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597010/longest-common-subsequence

Comment: Not just the longest one. I do want all combinations, but only the longest ones without overlapping words based on the first array.

Comment: So is the second "the" a match or is not? Since it doesn't overlap.

Comment: Can you provide more details? In the above example, the userSelect array only has a single instance of "the" so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with

```
var matches = 
    (from l in userSelect.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
     join r in original.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }) 
     on l.s equals r.s 
     group l by r.i - l.i into g
     from m in g.Select((l, j) => new { l.i, j = l.i - j, k = g.Key })
     group m by new { m.j, m.k } into h
     select h.Select(t => t.i).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

This will output

```
matches[0] // { 0, 1, 2 } the quick brown
matches[1] // { 4, 5 } jumps over
matches[2] // { 0 } the 
matches[3] // { 3 } dog
```

Using the input `{"the", "quick", "brown", "the", "lazy", "dog"}` yields:

```
matches[0] // { 0, 1, 2 } the quick brown
matches[1] // { 0 } the 
matches[2] // { 3 } the
matches[3] // { 3, 4, 5 } the lazy dog
```

Note that the calls to `ToArray` are optional. If you don't actually need the results in an array you can leave that out and save a little processing time.

To filter out any sequences that are *completely contained* with other larger sequences, you can run this code (note the `orderby` in the modified query):

```
var matches = 
    (from l in userSelect.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
     join r in original.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }) 
     on l.s equals r.s 
     group l by r.i - l.i into g
     from m in g.Select((l, j) => new { l.i, j = l.i - j, k = g.Key })
     group m by new { m.j, m.k } into h
     orderby h.Count() descending
     select h.Select(t => t.i).ToArray());

int take = 0;
var filtered = matches.Where(m => !matches.Take(take++)
                                          .Any(n => m.All(i => n.Contains(i))))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Will this work right if userSelect is `{"the", "quick", "brown", "the", "lazy", "dog"}`?

Comment: In that case it outputs `{ { 0 }, { 3 }, { 1, 2 }, { 0 }, { 3, 4, 5 } }`. What would the desired output be?

Comment: I would expect, based on the OP's description, `{ {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5} }'

Comment: Jim Mischel's output is the correct output that I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @rotaercz back to the drawing board I guess. Give me some time to work on it.

Comment: I'm definitely interested to see a LINQ solution. I'm always amazed at what LINQ can do.

Comment: @rotaercz See my updated answer. It's still not filtering out overlapping sequences, but it's getting closer. What should the expected result be if the input is `{"the", "quick", "brown", "quick", "brown", "fox" }`?

Comment: Yeah, that is really close.

Comment: @rotaercz see my update for filtering contained sub-sequences. It's not pretty (and I wouldn't use it for huge sequences) but it works!

Comment: I was testing it. I think the filter may have a bug? I tried the following...
userSelect: { "the", "driver", "was", "surprised", ";", "the", "sled", "moved", "." }
original: { "the", "driver", "was", "surprised", ",", "too", ";", "the", "sled", "had", "not", "moved", "." }

Comment: The results I got were `{ { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 }` which corresponds to "`the driver was surprised`", "`; the sled`" and "`moved .`". That looks correct to me. What should the result be?

Comment: You're right, it's working correctly! My for loop to the console was incorrect.

Comment: I found a new bug. Could you please fix it? I tried the following...
userSelect: {"the", "sled", "had", "not", "moved", ";", "the", "driver", "was", "surprised", "."} original: {"the", "driver", "was", "surprised", ",", "too", ";", "the", "sled", "had", "not", "moved", "."}

I got: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {5,6}, {10}}.
Notice the overlap of 6.

Comment: In this scenario it should return: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10}}

Comment: @rotaercz That was kind of by design. I only filtered out lists which were completely contained within (subsets of) larger lists. Here element 6 appears in a larger list but 5 does not, so it won't be excluded. However, you can easily change the `All` in my filter code to `Any` to filter out any overlaps. I think this function will be less well behaved when you have two overlapping sequences of the same length, but perhaps that's okay for your purposes.

Comment: Oh, you already replied! Wow, that was fast. Actually it should be: In this scenario it should return: {{0,1,2,3,4}, {5}, {6}, {7,8,9}, {10}}

Comment: I actually agree that the answer you provided for this question is optimal. I'll put this up as a new question. Perhaps you'd like to give it a go? :)

Comment: I put up a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235221/find-overlapping-values-in-2-dimensional-array-and-extract-to-new-array

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't understand why you said it should return `{ {0,1,2,3,4}, {5}, {6}, {7,8,9}, {10} }`. I can probably tweak it to return `{ {0,1,2,3,4}, {5}, {6,7,8,9}, {10} }` or `{ {0,1,2,3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10} }`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier if words couldn't be repeated . . .

The general idea is to create a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` from the original word list. That will tell you which words are used at what positions. The dictionary for your sample would be:

```
key="the", value={0, 6}
key="quick", value={1}
key="brown", value={2}
... etc
```

Now, when you get the user's input, you step through it sequentially, looking up the words in your dictionary to get the list of positions.

So you look up a word and it's in the dictionary. You save the position(s) returned from the dictionary. Look up the next word. There are three conditions you need to handle:

1. The word isn't in the dictionary. Save your previous consecutive grouping and go to the next word, where you'll potentially start a new group.
2. The word is in the dictionary, but the none of the positions returned match the expected positions (the expected positions being one more than the saved positions from the last word). Save your previous consecutive group and go to the next word, where you'll potentially start a new group.
3. The word is in the dictionary and one of the returned positions matches the expected position. Save those positions and go to the next word.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: This is very close to the direction I was thinking in too. I just had a hard time converting it to code.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do exactly what you would like but it's an a really clean and simple way to get a new array with all of the common strings (ie take the intersection of the two arrays).

```
var results = array1.Intersect(array2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

After executing the `resutls` array will have every string (ignoring case) that occurs in both `array1` and `array2`.

If you want a bit of theory the intersect method is based on the intersection operation you do on sets in lambda calculus. The collections in C# implement all the common set operations so it's worth having some familiarity of them. Here's a link to the wiki article; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)

Comment: This doesn't help because all values of the userSelect array will always be returned every time based on your code in all my examples.

Comment: @rotaercz I don't really understand what you're saying. That is not how intersection works. If I intersect the following arrays; `{ 1, 2, 4, 7 }` and `{ 2, 7, 9, 10, 11 }` the result would be `{ 2, 7 }`. Your second block of code makes no sense. It's hard coding the indexes of the intersection of the source array and the strings in the comment. Why take the indexes when you can take the elements themselves?

Comment: The second block of code are the results that I want which are a list of arrays with the index values of the userSelect array saved out. I'm looking for longest consecutive matches. For example: { A, B, D, G } and { B, D, G, Y, Z } would result in:

{ 1, 2, 3 }

because B, D, G are in the 1, 2, 3 indexes of the first array.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very elegant but efficient. When it comes to indices Linq makes it often more complicated and less efficient then simple loops.

```
string[] userSelect = new string[] { "the", "quick", "brown", "dog", "jumps", "over" };
string[] original = new string[] { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog" };
var consecutiveGroups = new Dictionary<int, IList<string>>();
IList<Tuple<int, string>> uniques = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

int maxIndex = Math.Min(userSelect.Length, original.Length);
if (maxIndex > 0)
{
    int minIndex = 0;
    int lastMatch = int.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
    {
        var us = userSelect[i];
        var o = original[i];
        if (us == o)
        {
            if (lastMatch == i - 1)
                consecutiveGroups[minIndex].Add(us);
            else
            {
                minIndex = i;
                consecutiveGroups.Add(minIndex, new List<string>() { us });
            }
            lastMatch = i;
        }
        else
            uniques.Add(Tuple.Create(i, us));
    }
}
```

output the indices of the consecutive groups + the indices of the uniques:

```
var consecutiveGroupsIndices = consecutiveGroups
    .OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Value.Count)
    .Select(kv => Enumerable.Range(kv.Key, kv.Value.Count).ToArray()
    .ToArray());
foreach(var consIndexGroup in consecutiveGroupsIndices)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", consIndexGroup));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", uniques.Select(u => u.Item1)));
```

Comment: I was trying to test out your answer but I'm using .NET 3.5 for my Android project, so I can't use Tuples.

Comment: @rotaercz: Then just use a `List<int>` and add the indices of the unique items or a `List<string>` if you want to see the string. I have used a second collection because the unique items don't belong to the _consecutive groups_ at all but you want to see them anyway as your desired output suggests.

Comment: Do I just replace Tuple<int, string> with List<string>? I'm not familiar with Tuple objects.

Comment: @rotaercz: No, i presume that you want to see only the indices and of the uniques. Then you have to use a `List<int>`. So replace `IList<Tuple<int, string>> uniques = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();` with `var uniques = new List<int>()`. Then replace the one-liner `uniques.Add(Tuple.Create(i, us));` with `uniques.Add(i)`. Note that the `String.Join` with an `IEnumerable<string>` overload was also new in .NET 4. So you have to convert them to an array with `ToArray`. For example (for the uniques at the end): `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", uniques.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray()));`.

Comment: It provides the same result as in your question. The main results are in the dictionary where the key is the min index of each group and the value is the list of all consecutive strings.

Answer (score 0):

### Use LINQ for added fun

After a few tries I came up with a pure LINQ solution that theoretically can be an one-liner. I did try to make it efficient, but of course functional solutions will result in duplicate computations since you cannot keep state.

We start off with a little pre-processing to save on duplicate computations later. Yes, I know what I 'm doing with index is a questionable practice, but if you are careful it works and it gets there fast:

```
var index = 0;
var lookup = original.ToLookup(s => s, s => index++);
```

### The monstrosity

```
var occurrences = userSelect
  .Where(lookup.Contains)
  .SelectMany((s, i) => lookup[s]
    .Select(j => new {
      User = userSelect.Skip(i),
      Original = original.Skip(j),
      Skipped = i
    })
    .Select(t => t.User.Zip(t.Original, (u, v) => Tuple.Create(u, v, t.Skipped))
                       .TakeWhile(tuple => tuple.Item1 == tuple.Item2)
    )
    .Select(u => new { 
      Word = s, 
      Start = u.Select(v => v.Item3).Min(), 
      Length = u.Count()
    })
  )
  .GroupBy(v => v.Start + v.Length)
  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(u => u.Start).First())
  .GroupBy(v => v.Word)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u => u.Length).First())
  .Select(w => Enumerable.Range(w.Start, w.Length).ToArray())
  .ToList();
```

Printing this with

```
foreach (var occurrence in occurrences) {
  Console.WriteLine(
    "Maximal match starting with '{0}': [{1}]",
    userSelect[occurrence[0]],
    string.Join(", ", occurrence)
  );
}
```

gives

```
Maximal match starting with 'the': [0, 1, 2]
Maximal match starting with 'dog': [3]
Maximal match starting with 'jumps': [4, 5]
```

It's immediately obvious that **you would not want to use this code in production**, another (procedural) solution would be preferable by far. However, this solution has the distinction of being purely functional except for `lookup`. Of course that can also be written functionally:

```
var lookup = original.Select((s, i) => Tuple.Create)
                     .ToLookup(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
```

### How it works

Warming up, it creates a dictionary-like structure that associates each word in `original` to the indexes where it appears in the same collection. This will be used later to create as many matching sequences as possible from each word in `userSelect` (e.g. "the" will result it two matching sequences because it appears twice in `original`).

Then:

```
.Where(lookup.Contains)
```

This is easy, it removes from consideration all words in `userSelect` that do not appear in `original`.

```
 // For each place where the word s appears in original...
.SelectMany((s, i) => lookup[s]
  // Define the two subsequences of userSelect and original to work on.
  // We are trying to find the number of identical elements until first mismatch.
  .Select(j => new { User = userSelect.Skip(i), Original = original.Skip(j), Skipped = j })

  // Use .Zip to find this subsequence
  .Select(t => t.User.Zip(t.Original, (u, v) => Tuple.Create(u, v, t.Skipped)).TakeWhile(tuple => tuple.Item1 == tuple.Item2))

  // Note the index in original where the subsequence started and its length
  .Select(u => new { Word = s, Start = u.Select(v => v.Item3).Min(), Length = u.Count() })
)
```

At this point we have projected each matching word in `userSelect` to an anonymous object with `Start` and `Length` properties. However, sequences where the matching length is N will also have resulted in smaller matching sequences of length N-1, N-2, ... 1.

The key here is to realize that for all subsequences in such sets `Start + Length` is going to be the same; moreover, subsequences from different sets will have different sums of `Start + Length`. So let's take advantage to trim the results down:

```
// Obvious from the above
.GroupBy(v => v.Start + v.Length)

// We want to keep the longest subsequence. Since Start + Length is constant for
// all, it follows the one with the largest Length has the smallest Start:
.Select(g => g.OrderBy(u => u.Start).First())
```

This will still leave us with as many matches for each word in `userSelect` as times that word appears in `original`. So let's also cut that down to the longest match:

```
.GroupBy(v => v.Word)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(u => u.Length).First())
```

We now have an object like `{ Word = "the", Start = 0, Length = 3 }`. Let's convert that to an array of indexes in `userSelect`:

```
.Select(w => Enumerable.Range(w.Start, w.Length).ToArray())
```

And finally put all these arrays in the same collection and mission accomplished!