# Find overlapping values in 2 dimensional array and extract to new array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following code which works as it should:

```
string[] userSelect = new string[] {"the", "sled", "had", "not", "moved", ";", "the", "driver", "was", "surprised", "."};
string[] original = new string[] {"the", "driver", "was", "surprised", ",", "too", ";", "the", "sled", "had", "not", "moved", "."};

var matches = 
    (from l in userSelect.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
     join r in original.Select((s, i) => new { s, i }) 
     on l.s equals r.s 
     group l by r.i - l.i into g
     from m in g.Select((l, j) => new { l.i, j = l.i - j, k = g.Key })
     group m by new { m.j, m.k } into h
     select h.Select(t => t.i).ToArray())
    .ToArray();

// remove filter overlaps
int take = 0;
var filtered = matches.Where(m => !matches.Take(take++)
    .Any(n => m.All(i => n.Contains(i))))
    .ToArray();
```

Using the above I get the result of:

```
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {6,7,8,9}, {5,6}, {10}}
```

Notice the overlap of 6. Because {"the", "driver", "was", "surprised"} and {";", "the"} are both in the original sentence.

I need a secondary filter for cases like these. It should find the overlap of all values like this and extract them to independent arrays so there is no index value overlap. The output should separate the overlaps to look like the following:

```
{{0,1,2,3,4}, {7,8,9}, {10}, {6}, {5}}
```

Comment: You might want to talk us through what that code actually does. I'm sure I could work it out but I shouldn't need to have to and if your problem isn't obvious to people reading it then they are less inclined to answer.

Comment: The above code is made to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074935/how-to-compare-2-string-arrays-and-find-all-consecutive-matches-and-save-indices?lq=1