# Longest Common Subsequence

Tags: c#, string, matrix, backtracking, lcs

Hi this is my code for longest common subsequence for 2 strings in c# . I need help in backtracking . I need to find out the subsequence : GTCGT

```
String str1 = "GTCGTTCG";
String str2 = "ACCGGTCGAGTG";

int[,] l = new int[str1.Length, str2.Length]; // String 1 length and string 2      length storing it in a 2-dimensional array
int lcs = -1;
string substr = string.Empty;
int end = -1;

for (int i = 0; i <str1.Length ; i++) // Looping based on string1 length 
{                
  for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++) // Looping based on string2 Length
  {                  
    if (str1[i] == str2[j]) // if match found 
    {
      if (i == 0 || j == 0)  // i is first element or j is first elemnt then array [i,j] = 1
      {
        l[i, j] = 1;
      }
      else
      {   
        l[i, j] = l[i - 1, j - 1] + 1; // fetch the upper value and increment by 1 
      }

      if (l[i, j] > lcs)
      {
        lcs = l[i, j]; // store lcs value - how many time lcs is found 
        end = i; // index on longest continuous string
      }

    }
    else // if match not found store zero initialze the array value by zero
    {
      l[i, j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay? What is your question?

Comment: Homework?  If not, http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#C.23

Comment: @AustinSalonen not homework . But am stuck . I dont know how to print. Should I use another table ? initially I was using substring . But I want subsequence . How do I print the values in my array l. I mean how do I backtrack at as given in the algorithm

Comment: Best advice I can give is to step through the linked implementation and see where you're messing up.

Comment: Check out [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77944515/8644294). It has the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return a collection of strings. There might be several longest common sub-sequence with same length.

```
public List<string> LCS(string firstString, string secondString)
{
    // to create the lcs table easier which has first row and column empty.
    string firstStringTemp = " " + firstString;
    string secondStringTemp = " " + secondString;

    // create the table
    List<string>[,] temp = new List<string>[firstStringTemp.Length, secondStringTemp.Length];

    // loop over all items in the table.
    for (int i = 0; i < firstStringTemp.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondStringTemp.Length; j++)
        {

            temp[i, j] = new List<string>();
            if (i == 0 || j == 0) continue;
            if (firstStringTemp[i] == secondStringTemp[j])
            {
                var a = firstStringTemp[i].ToString();
                if (temp[i - 1, j - 1].Count == 0)
                {
                    temp[i, j].Add(a);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (string s in temp[i - 1, j - 1])
                    {
                        temp[i, j].Add(s + a);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                List<string> b = temp[i - 1, j].Concat(temp[i, j - 1]).Distinct().ToList();
                if (b.Count == 0) continue;
                int max = b.Max(p => p.Length);
                b = b.Where(p => p.Length == max).ToList();
                temp[i, j] = b;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp[firstStringTemp.Length - 1, secondStringTemp.Length - 1];
}
```

You need to have a collection set in each entry of table. So you can still keep different strings with the same length in each cell of table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood your question, I think you want to know the subsequence value i.e. that string. So, to get the subsequence, I've learnt a little bit differently. First, I calculate the table the one we do in standard Longest Common Subsequence (LCS) problem. Then I traverse the table to get the subsequence value. Sorry, I'm not familiar with C#, so, I will give you CPP code. Please have a look and let me know if you face any problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


string printLongestCommonSubsequence(vector<vector<int> >& dp, int m, int n, string text1, string text2){
    int i = m, j = n;
    string lcs = "";
    while(i > 0 && j > 0){
        if(text1[i-1] == text2[j-1]){
            lcs.push_back(text1[i-1]);
            i--; j--;
        }
        else{
            if(dp[i][j-1] > dp[i-1][j]) j--;
            else i--;
        }
    }
    reverse(lcs.begin(), lcs.end());
    return lcs;
}

string longestCommonSubsequence(string text1, string text2){
    int m = text1.size();
    int n = text2.size();
    vector<vector<int> > dp(m+1, vector<int>(n+1));

    //initialization
    for(int i=0; i<m+1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n+1; j++){
            if(i == 0 || j == 0) dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    //solving the subproblems to solve the bigger problems
    for(int i=1; i<m+1; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<n+1; j++){
            if(text1[i-1] == text2[j-1])
                dp[i][j] = 1 + dp[i-1][j-1];
            else
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]);
        }
    }

    return printLongestCommonSubsequence(dp, m, n, text1, text2);
}

int main(){
    string text1, text2;
    cout<<"Enter the first string: ";
    cin>>text1;
    cout<<"\nEnter the second string: ";
    cin>>text2;

    string lcs = longestCommonSubsequence(text1, text2);
    cout<<"Longest Common Subsequence is: "<<lcs<<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

[image]

Please have a look at the diagram.
With respect to printing the LCS,
The basic idea is:

1. When the characters are equal of both the strings then move towards diagonal.
2. When the characters are not equal of both the strings then move towards the maximum of both the directions.

I hope this helps 
Happy Learning
Thanks